# how to bind different POST objects with one request mapping in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

Here is how my url looks like

http://localhost/controller/check

Here is the requestmapping

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public Data check(@RequestBody final Check checkRequest, final HttpServletResponse servletResponse) {
    // service layer
 }
```

Now I want the `Check` object to handle both the following POJOS.

```
public class Check {
    String name;
    String email;
}

public class Check {
    int age;
    Location location;
}
```

The request mapping should handle the following `POST` body.

```
{"age" : 23, "location" :{ "region": XXX, "country":"xxx", "zipcode":xxx}
```

and

```
{"name": "yyyy", "email":"hello@bar.com"}
```

what is the recommended approach here?

Answer (score 0):

If it makes sense just combine the attributes into just 1 class. The json mapping will work with the missing atributes will be mapped to null.

If you still need 2 different models create a wrapper called `CheckRequest` which has 2 memeber variables checkName & checkLocation and post the appropriate json

Comment: one of the `Check` is already in use. so it cannot be changed

Comment: Then I suggest you create a wrapper

Comment: The client is already using Check object. If I create a wrapper, then the client needs to use the wrapper to send incoming POST object. If not, explain in code what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I will extend the `Check` class and will put the newly extended class in the request body.